# How to compile vlc library for android using MAC?

Tags: android, vlc

I want to generate .so files for my android app.Is there any tutorial to compile vlc library for android using mac , i know [this tutorial](https://wiki.videolan.org/AndroidCompile) which explains using Ubuntu.Does anyone knows similar for Mac ?

Comment: Do you want vlc library because you need to do video conversion/compression? I know this didn't deal with a subject of your question, but only to give you some other opportunities do you know that: http://writingminds.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/ (just curious)

Comment: @shadowsheep  i have an old vlc library in my app which i want to replace with new one. I don't want video conversion and compression

Comment: @shadowsheep thanks man will check that and let you know :)

Comment: You could run an Ubuntu docker container on Mac and build things

Comment: @cricket_007 never used it before, is it gonna take time? I mean are those commands will be same if i use docker?

Comment: Docker or virtual machine... Yes, commands are same. Ubuntu is still the same.  Point being - if you cannot find instructions for Mac, then that's what I would recommend

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks man will try that if i didn't find any alternatives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As cricket_007  suggested VM is the option for my case. I was not able to find the instructions for MAC. So i compiled it using linux on VM.